# Visual Studio 2019 Image Editor won't bring up when clicking on an image file

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019, image-editor

I [installed the 'Image and 3D model editors' component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/image-editor?view=vs-2019), but when I click on a .png (icon) file from my Xamarin Forms solution, I get this pop up error:

> There is no editor available for
> 'C:\Users\...\MySolution\MyProject.Android\Resources\mipmap-xxxhdpi\launcher_foreground.png'.
>
> Make sure the application for the file type (.png) is installed.

Do I also have to enable the component somewhere? What am I missing here?

EDIT: If I right click on the image and 'Open With...', then I get these options:
[image]

The first (Default) option would give me this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to **right click** your image file,and select **Open With...** -> **Graphics Designers**.

Then you will open the image with the **Image Editor**.

Comment: I tred that already. I'm updating my question, so you can see what options I have...

Comment: @Tomo What's your visual studio version,try to update to the latest version.

Comment: @Tomo Did you try to reinstall it ?

Comment: Yep. Repair, reinstall, even system restore point.

Comment: Could you try to editor in a new project,see if it works.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT i too am having the same problem with Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise 16.10.4

Comment: Same issue here. Except my MS Test result contains a link to the screenshot .png for the failed test and gives me the same problem. VS 2019 16.10.4